# C++: create a pointer in a program and access that location in another program

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory

So, is it possible to create a pointer in C++ like this, and print it out:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int* ptr = new int;
    (*ptr) = 3;
    std::cout << ptr << '\n';
}
```

And then run it, copy the value of ptr, and in another program, while this is running, do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main() {
    long long pointer;
    std::cin >> pointer;
    int* ptr = nullptr;
    std::memcpy(&ptr, &pointer, sizeof(pointer));
    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
}
```

And get 3 printed out? Is it possible, or if not, then exactly why?

Comment: I think you're looking for what's known as a pipe, or shared memory.

Comment: Well tbh, I don't want to use this for some purpose or at least now, that's mainly a theoratical question.

Comment: This is not possible. Programs uses virtual memory that it gets from the OS. A memory address in one program will usually not point to the same place as the same address in a different program.

Comment: @Andrew as the question is currently written it cannot be answered as this is API and OS specific. The best we can do is to say "Pipe or shared memory" which are the general mechanisms for doing this sort of thing. But there are others means.

Comment: Looks like a XY problem. You can have a look at Boost.Interprocess to get some gory details of sharing data between processes (which as other already pointed out is not as easy as sharing a pointer value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible in standard C++. Standard C++ does not have a concept of program**s**. There is only one program as far as the language is concerned - the one that is being translated at the moment.

Outside of the C++ standard, multi-tasking operating systems do exist, where it is possible to run multiple processes simultaneously (you are probably using one right now). Such operating systems use virtual memory, and one process cannot directly access virtual memory of another process.

It is technically possible though for example using `process_vm_readv` system call (Linux specific), if you have sufficient permissions. Before using such trick, you must somehow communicate th process id and virtual address that you want to read, which are not known until the first program runs.

Although it may be possible, this is probably not something that you need to do, unless you are implementing a debugger or similar tool perhaps. If you want this simply so that the processes can communicate, there are other ways. No C++-standard ways, because C++ doesn't know of processes, but for example POSIX standard specifies many ways for processes to communicate: shared memory, files, network sockets etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it out, and it didn't work, the second program printed out some random value in the second program

Comment: @Andrew There might be something wrong with something that you did.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in standard c++. This is because the program memory are virtual, and you can’t access other program’s memories because they are in a separate virtual memory. A pipe would work for what you want.